# Call batch file in each sub folder recursively, then delete it?

Tags: batch-file

So here is my dilemna...
I have multiple subfolders in a directory.
I need to loop through those subfolders, and start a batch file in each.
the batch file needed will be copied to each subfolder that has a .ini file.

Note:
I am working with JREPL.bat which will replace text in each .ini file in each subfolder and will be called from the replace.bat file.

The problem is that it only works for 1 subfolder and not all of them.
the names of each subfolder is different. how to get it work with all?

Here is what I am working with

```
@echo on
SET "curentdirectory="%CD%"
for /r %%F in (*.ini) do @for %%A in ("%%F\..") do call replace.bat "%%F"
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Initial remark: I have no idea how this works with too many double-quotes. Should be `"curentdirectory=%CD%"` and `call replace.bat`.

Comment: I am looking to call the bat files that were copied into each folder that contains a .ini file..

Comment: You have an extra double-quotes : `replace.bat"`.

Comment: Noticed that...  Thanks!   So breaking this down in simple terms,  I am looking to run a batch file from directory root to run a bat file (replace.bat) in all sub folders in directory.  Also I fixed the code for only whats needed.

Comment: More cleaning up to do. This seems redundant : `@for %%A in ("%%F\..")  do`

Comment: I see no reason to **copy** the batch just to process an `.ini` file in varying locations. I suggest to let the batch file call itself with a location argument, the first invocation without arg iterating the subfolders.